# Не обновляется adapter в фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview.adapter

Почему-то не сразу обновляется *adapter*. В фрагменте, в `onStart` я использую самописный метод `checkActiveTasks`(находится в классе `TaskTimeChecker`). Он сравнивает дату окончания задачи с сегодняшней датой и если дата окончания больше сегодняшней, то он перекидывает это задачу в другой фрагмент(удаляет из таблицы БД одного фрагмента и добавляет в таблицу другого). Проблема в том, что не сразу пропадает удаленная задача(пример в видео).

**Видео, демонстрация проблемы:** [ТЫК](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94Fm8mOfeX0) или https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94Fm8mOfeX0

*Пояснение к видео*. Когда я сменил дату, задача не сразу удалилась, а удалилась только после того, как я вернулся на этот фрагмент с другого фрагмента.

**Код фрагмента:**

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

private DBHelper dbHelper;
private ArrayList<Items> elements;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TaskTimeChecker taskTimeChecker;
private TaskAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    taskTimeChecker = new TaskTimeChecker(setZeroTimeDate(new Date()).getTime(),
            getContext());

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
    adapter = new TaskAdapter(dbHelper.elementsHome(), "home");

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    taskTimeChecker.checkActiveTasks();

    //.elementsHome() - получение данных из БД 
    elements = dbHelper.elementsHome();
    //.dateChange это тот же notifyDataSetChange, пример ниже
    adapter.dataChange(dbHelper.elementsHome());
}

private Date setZeroTimeDate(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    return date;
}
```

**TaskAdapter.dateChange:**

```
public void dataChange(ArrayList<Items> elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Проверьте, сколько по времени у Вас занимает выполнение этой строки `elements = dbHelper.elementsHome();`? Может, просто, БД очень медленно данные получает?

Comment: Каким образом мне это сделать, если не секрет?

Comment: `long millis = System.currentTimeMillis(); elements = dbHelper.elementsHome(); long millis2 = System.currentTimeMillis(); Log.e("YOUR_LOG_TAG", millis2-millis);` Выведет в LogCat время выполнения в миллисекундах

Comment: Нет, с этим всё в порядке. 1-2 миллисекунды

Comment: Извините, я немного неправильно понял Вашу проблему) Перенесите код из onStart в onResume, должно помочь

Comment: Тоже не помогает. После паузы сначала выполняет onStart, а потом onResume

Comment: и переинициализируйте taskTimeChecker там же! У него сохраняется старая дата! Да, на счет onResume я погорячился, давно жизненный цикл фрагментов не вспоминал

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё в точку. Помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш `TaskTimeChecker` инициализировался в `onCreateView`. Данный метод жизненного цикла не вызывается повторно при возвращении фрагмента на экран. Так как инициализация включала в себя сохранение текущей даты, после изменения даты на устройстве, изменения `TaskTimeChecker` не получал.

```
taskTimeChecker = new TaskTimeChecker(setZeroTimeDate(new Date()).getTime(),
        getContext()); // вот этот кусок кода
```

Всё, что нужно сделать - перенести инициализацию `TaskTimeChecker` в метод `onStart`